# In the custom hook test, the state is not changed from the initial value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm testing my custom hook with Jest and React testing library.

In the custom hook test, I tried to change the state value and test it, but it changes from the initial value.

I'm going to explain it in detail with examples.

Firstly, take look at my custom hook and test code.

This is my custom hook.

- Custom hook

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const useCount = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(100);

  const increment = () => {
    console.log(count, 'inside increment');
    setCount(count + 1)
  }
  const decrement = () => {
    console.log(count, 'inside decrement');
    setCount(count - 1)
  }

  return { count, setCount, increment, decrement }
}
```

This is the test code.

- Test code

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { act, renderHook } from '@testing-library/react-hooks';

import { useCount } from '../src/usecase/useCount';

describe('test', () => {
  test('test', () => {
    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useCount());
    act(() => {
      result.current.setCount(0);
      result.current.increment();
    })
    expect(result.current.count).toBe(1) // In this line, I hope count is 1 but it is 101 because initial value is 100 and it was added to 1.
  })
});
```

The `count` is 100 initially, and `increase` method adds 1 to the `count` from the count current value.

So I want the `score` in the test code to be `1`. Because the `score` was set `0` firstly in the test code, and after that, the score was added 1 by `increase` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you change initialValue and run the function in the same render. so the expected will become your init (100) + 1 @testing-library

and in test code you can put them like this

```
...

describe('test', () => {
  test('test', () => {
    const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useCount());
      
    //run setCount to change initial value
    act(() => {
    result.current.setCount(0);
  })

  // make it rerender
    rerender()
  
  // run your count
    act(() => {
      result.current.increment();
    })
    expect(result.current.count).toBe(1) // In this line, I hope count is 1 but it is 101 because initial value is 100 and it was added to 1.
  })
});

...
```